# How do I query a mysql table to get the current value of a column and the max for the day

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table that looks something like this. It updates every 5 minutes for each game_id

```
game_id  players   date
12       420       2013-06-19 12:30:00
13       345       2013-06-19 12:30:00
14       600       2013-06-19 12:30:00
12       375       2013-06-19 12:25:00     
13       475       2013-06-19 12:25:00
14       575       2013-06-19 12:25:00
12       500       2013-06-19 12:20:00
...
```

I need a query for each game id, get the current players (latest timestamp) and the max for the day. so the results would look like this

```
game_id  max      current
12       500      420
13       475      345
14       600      600
```

I tried something like this but, had no luck and can't figure it out :(

select game_id, max(players) as max, players as current from players where date >= '2013-06-19' order by date desc group by game_id;

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last value, you need a trick of one sort or another.  Instead of using a join, this version uses the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select game_id, max(players) as MaxPlayers,
       substring_index(group_concat(players order by date desc), ',', 1) + 0 as Latest
from players
group by game_id;
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it is guaranteed to work and does not require any additional joins.

In particular, it does *not* use the MySQL extension that allows columns to be included in the `select` clause without their being in the `group by` clause.  The results are indeterminate when there are multiple values, as expressly stated in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html):

> You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding
>   unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful
>   primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in
>   the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose
>   any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values
>   chosen are indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5157/5

```
 select game_id, max(players) as maximum, 
players as current 
from tab where date >= '2013-06-19' 

group by game_id
```

Comment: thanks but it is still not correctly returning the right values for the current column

Comment: @nevermind . . . Please the the reference in my answer below.  You are using a MySQL feature which the documentation expressly states is not reliable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, great, i have just tried... and fail :). I am reading your answer, and learning. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
select game_id, max(players) as max, players as current from players  where date >= '2013-06-19' group by game_id  order by date desc ;
```

Comment: That gets the right max values, but it's not getting the most recent values correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  t.game_id
  , maxes.max_players as max
  , t.players as current_players as current
from
  (
    select
      t.game_id
      , max(t.players) as max_players
      , max(t.date) as max_date
    from
      t
    where
      t.game_id = :game_id
      and t.date >= :todays_date
    group by
      t.game_id
  ) maxes
  inner join t on t.game_id = maxes.game_id and t.date = maxes.max_date
where
  t.date >= :todays_date
```

I don't have a mysql db configured to test this right now but I think it will give you the desired results.